# Error Spring Roo database reverse engineer

Tags: reverse-engineering, spring-roo

When I run:

database reverse engineer --schema dbo --includeTables "SOL_*"

I receive the following message:

Created ROOT\src\main\resources\dbre.xml
Undo create ROOT\src\main\resources\dbre.xml
Byte no válido 2 de la secuencia UTF-8 de 2 bytes

Comment: Have you got any special chars on table definitions (like "ñ", acute vocals or "ç")? Which is the Char encoding of target database?

Comment: Yes, I have acute vocals on some tables definitions. Database char encoding is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare DB connection with UTF8 (using connection parameters). This way DB Metadata will be get by Roo using this encoding and dbre.xml file should be generated without problems.

If the problem persist, create a new bug on [Spring-Roo jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO).

Anyway, IMHO use non-ANSI characters for identifiers, whatever identifiers are on DB or source code, is a bad idea.

Good luck!